# Create install media - lion -command not found

Tags: macos, usb, install

I am trying to create a bootable usb drive in order to rebuild my sons old imac. I have followed the instructions given on this and other forums but am getting `command not found` when trying to run either of the commands

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ Mac\ OS\ X\ Lion.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ Mac\ OS\ X\ Lion.app —nointeraction

sudo /Applications/InstallMacOSXLion.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/InstallMacOSXLion.app
```

to create a USB installer. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please add links to the other postings you are referring to and also what the result is you are getting? You won't get good answers if people have to guess what exactly the result of these commands is when running on your system.

Comment: I am getting "command not found" when using the above syntax as per the above subject heading. One of the other postings on this forum suggested removing backslashes. I have demonstrated this above in my examples.

Comment: @startingtopuff, You're getting the "command not found" error because, as I said in my answer, "_Mac OS X Lion didn't come with the built-in ability to create a USB installer ..._".

Comment: DOH!! Just browsed application path and found "createinstallmedia" exec doesnt exist in either Lion or Mountain Lion. Not surprised command line didnt work.

Answer (score 4):

Mac OS X Lion didn't come with the built-in ability to create a USB installer since a small USB flash drive installer came with Mac's that shipped with Mac OS X Lion and was also sold by Apple on a small USB flash drive.  It was also downloadable through the App Store.  It was the first release of Mac OS X to not come on optical media.

To create a USB Installer, from the downloaded Install Mac OS X Lion application bundle, you'll need to use a program like [DiskMaker X (formerly Lion DiskMaker)](http://diskmakerx.com)

Surly because Apple sold the Mac OS X Lion USB Installer for ~$79 USD they weren't going to make it easy for users to usurp buying the product vs. making it themselves.  That changed with OS X Mavericks, being the first OS X release to include a built-in way to create a USB Installer.

To create a USB Installer for OS X Mavericks and later, have a look at: [Create a bootable installer for OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried using Diskmaker but it errored with "unable to eject volume" Have now purchased from Apple v10.8 Mountain Lion and Diskmaker completed process. Have tried booting up White imac using alt/option and just getting white screen (no startup manager). Tried booting holding "c" and just getting flashing exclamation mark. Any ideas?

Comment: @startingtopuff, the latest OS any Intel based white iMac Mid 2006 and earlier model is Mac OS X 10.6.8 and any Intel based white iMac Late 2006 and later model is Mac OS X 10.7.5 and is probably why you're having issues trying to boot a version later then that.